# Compiling D with Code::Blocks

Tags: compiler-construction, ide, d, codeblocks

I'm having trouble compiling D programs in Code::Blocks.  Here's what I'm doing:

1. In accordance with my organization conventions, I have unzipped the Digital Mars D2 compiler to `C:\Compilers\dmd2`.  I also have the Digital Mars C/C++ compiler at `C:\Compilers\dm`.
2. For the "Toolchain executables" tab in the "Global compiler settings" window, I have set the fields to...

   - Compiler installation directory: `C:\Compilers\dmd2\windows`
   - C compiler: `dmd.exe`
   - C++ compiler: `dmd.exe`
   - Linker for dynamic libs: `dmd.exe`
   - Linker for static libs: `lib.exe`
   - Debugger: `windbg.exe`
   - Resource compiler: `rcc.exe` **(This is the default file, which does not exist.  I'm not sure what to set this to.)**
   - Make program: `make.exe`
3. I have the following listed as additional paths:

   - `C:\Compilers\dmd2\windows\lib`
   - `C:\Compilers\dmd2\windows\bin`

When I start a new D project, I do not see any syntax highlighting.  Attempting to compile and run a simple "hello world" program results in the following error:

`"Hello World in D - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
Nothing to be done.`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit I finally got it to work.

I did a complete reinstall of everything Code::Blocks and Digital Mars.

When I was reinstalling Code::Blocks, I opted-in to the D lexer (which gives me syntax highlighting).

In the new D compiler folder, I removed the folders for Linux and OSX and moved the files from the Windows folder into the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is in fact causing the problem, but your C/C++ compiler should be `dmc`, *not* `dmd` (it's a different download package). Try fixing that, and seeing if that helps (although it might not).

Comment: Nope.  I added the path of my Digital Mars C/C++ compiler as an additional path and set the fields to `dmc`, bu the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The Compiler installation directory should be **C:\Compilers\dmd2**

Comment: The `dmd2` folder is further subdivided by platform.  There are no actual files there.